# Javascript click on iframe for chrome's audio click?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-audio

I have an HTML game where the audio is user submitted and played from within an invisible iframe with web audio.

I would like to play the audio without making the iframe into a button and making the user click on yet another thing when they're already interacting with the main site. Is there a good way to handle this? Is it possible to use javascript to transfer clicks on the main site onto the iframe or do there need to be a load of tricks used?

Comment: I'm afraid that's a security restriction of modern browsers these days. Any chance you can ditch the iframe?

Comment: @Milkmannetje Yes, I would undertake that if it's not possible to play the sound from the iframe. I want the user to be able to run their own howler.js inside a sandbox but in this case I would read their calls to howler in the iframe and then duplicate it on the outside, really annoying but if that's the only choice...

Comment: Hmm... maybe you can provide a code snippet? Or create an example on codepen or something? Maybe we can work something out from there...

Answer (score 0):

You can access the elements in `<iframe>` by using this:

```js
window.frames['yourIFrame'].document.getElementById('yourAudioElemId')
```

After doing so you should be able to start playing audio of that element by using the `.play()` method that is available to `<audio>` tag. This is all assuming that you are using `<audio>` and not `const audio = new Audio()`, because I think there is no chance of getting into `<iframe>`'s JavaScript.

Hope it helps.